# Something gets growing or to grow

Tags: meaning, verbs

1. > What if fungus gets growing on your toes.
2. > What if fungus gets to grow ...

Which one is correct to ask someone if they may get the disease?
What does #2 mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let me define a couple terms:

- **Inchoative** - indicates the beginning of a new state
- **Volitional** - an action that is done intentionally

Now, let's talk about *get*.

---

When inchoative *get* is used with an *-ing* clause like this, it's usually volitional.  You can say:

> ​1. We **got going** around five in the morning.

But it doesn't work for fungus growing on your toes, which is a non-volitional.  The fungus isn't doing it on purpose:

> ​2. *What if fungus **gets growing** on your toes?　←　*ungrammatical*

You can use *start* instead:

> ​3. What if fungus **starts growing** on your toes?

Inchoative *get* isn't always used for volitional predicates.  When it's used with adjectives, for example, it's often non-volitional:

> ​4. I **got sick** twice last year.

This is fine, even though getting sick isn't intentional.  Note that some adjectives end with *-ing*:

> ​5. This movie is **getting** really **exciting**!

This is fine because *exciting* is an adjective, not an *-ing* clause.

---

In this answer, the * symbol marks a sentence as ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone uses a *gets growing* form. Yes, you can *get* a disease:

> I **got** a fungus infection.

But the verb *grow* is OK by itself. If you need to refer to the beginning point, use *start*:

> What if fungus **grows** on your toes?
>   What if fungus **starts** growing on your toes?